# Angular4 Error trying to diff '[object Object]'

Tags: angular, http, service, bitcoin

I'm trying to display some info in the dom but I get this error:

> Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'

What Im trying to do is iterate over this data from https://www.surbtc.com/api/v2/markets/btc-clp/ticker:

> {"ticker":{"last_price":["1771455.0","CLP"],"min_ask":["1771432.0","CLP"],"max_bid":["1660003.0","CLP"],"volume":["178.37375119","BTC"],"price_variation_24h":"-0.107","price_variation_7d":"-0.115"}}

I want to display it in the html like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let price of prices">
    {{price.min_ask}}
    </div>
```

this is the service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { SurbtcMarket } from './surbtcmarket'


@Injectable()
export class SurbtcService {

  constructor(private http: Http, private surBtcMarket : SurbtcMarket) { }

  public getPricess() :Observable<SurbtcMarket> {
    return this.http.get('https://www.surbtc.com/api/v2/markets/btc-clp/ticker')
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }

}
```

Interface surbtcmarket.ts

```
export class SurbtcMarket {
public ticker: SurbtcMarketView[];
}

export class SurbtcMarketView {
  public last_price : number;
  public min_ask : number;
  public max_bid : number;
  public volume : number;
  public price_variation_24h : number;
  public price_variation_7d : number;
}
```

component.ts

```
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { SurbtcService } from '../../surbtc/surbtc.service';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comprarltc',
  templateUrl: './comprarltc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comprarltc.component.scss']
})
export class ComprarltcComponent implements OnInit {

  private prices = [];

  constructor(private surbtcService: SurbtcService) {
    this.surbtcService = surbtcService;
  }

ngOnInit(){
  this.surbtcService.getPricess()
  .subscribe(
    data => this.prices = data.ticker
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error trying to diff '\[object Object\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216857/error-trying-to-diff-object-object)

Comment: The response you get from `https://www.surbtc.com/api/v2/markets/btc-clp/ticker` is not a JSON array but a JSON object (1 instance of `SurbtcMarket` in your case). You cannot use `*ngFor` on an Object because you cannot loop over it.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle thanks for your reply. Is there a way to transform that object to an array?

Comment: Also, you mapped `ticker` as an array of type `SurbtcMarketView`but again, it's not an array, it is an object.

Comment: Yes you can wrap your 1 object in an array, but you shouldn't do that. Just correct your mappings (check the JSON spec on object / array) and remove use the *ngFor loop.

Comment: this is an 95% duplicate of your own question.  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552212/angular-4-object-object). Please stop polluting SO. Downvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have `price` as an array, then you have `push` the object in `prices` array.

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.surbtcService.getPricess()
  .subscribe(
    data => this.prices.push(data.ticker);
  );
}
```

OR, you can just directly access the object properties by assigning `data.ticker` to `prices`.

```
private prices = new SurbtcMarketView();

constructor(private surbtcService: SurbtcService) {

}
ngOnInit(){
   this.surbtcService.getPricess()
        .subscribe(data =>{
            this.prices = data.ticker;
        });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of prices.min_ask">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

UPDATE:

See the Plnkr [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/malbXKcARC6yImn9irl8?p=preview), I have resolved the issue that was causing error in parsing the json response.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Nehal. Now I get a typing error saying that property ticker does not exist on type surbtcMarket[]

Comment: Added a working Plnkr demo, please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again @Nehal. Now I get this error in the console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)".

Comment: That's a server error you have the resolve. Has nothing to do with angular. 
I was getting a CORS error for retrieving data from https://www.surbtc.com/api/v2/markets/btc-clp/ticker. So, I used the CORS chrome plugin to bypass the CORS error.

Answer (score 0):

Else you can also use this ,

```
prices : SurbtcService[] = [];
```

And then you can push the user object and make as a array,

```
this.prices.push(<<the data you want to push>>);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public getPricess() :Observable<SurbtcMarket> { return this.http.get('https://www.surbtc.com/api/v2/markets/btc-clp/ticker') .map((response: Response) => response.json() as SurbtcMarket); }
```

This might be due to the fact as it's not mapped to a type. And I assume this only retun one object otherwise you have to return an array.

```
public getPricess() :Observable<SurbtcMarket[]> { return this.http.get('https://www.surbtc.com/api/v2/markets/btc-clp/ticker') .map((response: Response) => response.json() as SurbtcMarket[]); }
```