# *ngFor="let hero of usersList" Error trying to diff. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm traying to understand why I cannot see in the html using ngFor all the users and there components in a table. It's seams that retain in usersList: User[] the response that is an array list of type User as in the next image
[PtrSCr of the Web page and the console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSGPn.png) but in the end it say that
Error: **Error trying to diff** '[{"id":101,"userName":"tcorneanu","password":"password","email":"tcorneanu@gmail.com"},{"id":104,"userName":"user3","password":"pwd3","email":"user3@gmail.com"}]'. **Only arrays and iterables are allowed**
**HTML**

```
<h2>User list</h2>
{{usersList}}
<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>index</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let hero of usersList; let i = index">
        <td>{{hero.id}}</td>
        <td>{{i}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**TS**

```
usersList: User[] = [];  

 private getUsersList(token:any):void{
    this.userService.getUsersList(token).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("data is: "+data),
      this.usersList = data
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

**userService**

```
getUsersList(token:any): Observable<User[]>{
    let tokenStr = 'Bearer '+token;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization",tokenStr);
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>(`${this.url}/users`,{headers, responseType: 'text' as 'json'});
  }
```

**User**

```
export interface  User {
    id: number;
    userName: string;
    password: string;
    email: string;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular4 Error trying to diff '\[object Object\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574249/angular4-error-trying-to-diff-object-object)

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: Did you check the `typeof data` ? Maybe its Response object and you are required to get the user array by using `data.json()`

Comment: @Kenny check his image url. He is getting plain string data of user array

Comment: I am afraid of maybe your data is type of `string`

Comment: @Kenny  
data is: [{"id":101,"userName":"tcorneanu","password":"password","email":"tcorneanu@gmail.com"},{"id":102,"userName":"user1","password":"pwd1","email":"user1@gmail.com"},{"id":103,"userName":"user2","password":"pwd2","email":"user2@gmail.com"},{"id":104,"userName":"user3","password":"pwd3","email":"user3@gmail.com"}]

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan console.log(typeof this.data) I see string in the console but I don't understand why because it should be of type User[]

Comment: in the same time if I try to do for example data.split('') it will tell me that Property 'split' does not exist on type 'User[]'.

Comment: I think `responseType` is unnecessary in userService because it seems that the response is being interpreted as a plain string instead of User[] array. Did you check the imports and proper usage of HttpClient?

Comment: [Andular documentation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)
/** GET heroes from the server */
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the string to User[] array

```
 private getUsersList(token:any):void{
    this.userService.getUsersList(token).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("data is: " +data+ typeof data),
      console.log("usersList type is: " +typeof this.usersList),
      this.string = data.toString(),
      console.log("string is of type "+typeof this.string+", value is "+this.string)
      this.array = JSON.parse(this.string);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

now if I go to the HTML
{{array}} I will see -> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

and table will show the table [Web Page and console in the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsJyj.png)

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>index</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let hero of array">
        <td>{{hero.userName}}</td>
        <td>{{hero.email}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```